# Overwriting library values from parent to child in Python class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am trying to design a Parent class that has several assigned attributes in a library.

```
class CC():
    Features = {"1" : "", "2" : ""}



class F(CC):
    Features["1"] = { key : value }
```

When I try to overwrite an element in the dictionary in the Child of that class (with a sub dictionary), it's giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Rough\Starting UP\AttributeInput.py", line 7, in <module>
    PersonClass = Fighter()
  File "C:\Python27\Rough\Starting UP\CharClass.py", line 45, in __init__
    classFeatures["1"] = {"Bonus Feat" : "Select a free feat from Fighter List"} 
NameError: global name 'classFeatures' is not defined
```

declaring the dictionary in global seems like a poor idea, so how can I override a specific element without breaking down the keys of "Features" into their own specific values?

**edited as below comment**

Comment: A tangential note: you define the original dict with a key `"1"`, which is a string, but then later you try to assign to the key `1`, an integer.  Inheritance issues aside, this will not overwrite the existing value but will create a new one, because the string `"1"` is not the same as the number `1`.

Comment: That was a typo on my entry here.  I didn't want to add the extra mash of code that I had outside the scope of the question.  Editted for fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access superclass attributes inside the class definition, because the class is not yet defined (it's still being defined), so it doesn't yet know what its superclasses are.  Also, note that if you could access them (or if you access them explicitly by doing `CC.Features`), you would be modifying the dict in `CC`, not creating a new dict in `F`.  So your changes in `F` would affect `CC`, which almost certainly isn't what you want.

One approach is to use a class decorator to modify the class after it's defined, for instance by merging its `Features` value with that of its superclasses.  This could also be done with a metaclass.

That is assuming that you actually want `Features` to be a class attribute.  It's unclear from your example, but in many cases it might be better to make it an instance attribute, in which case you would update it in `__init__`.

Perhaps you could give some more information about how you're using the `Feature` attribute and what you're hoping to accomplish with it.

Comment: working it into the __init__ statement seems to have fixed the flaw in the system.  I'm trying to design a class that has a lot of 'default' values to it, that child classes may overwrite.  There are many child classes so all of the attributes in the Parent will be altered, but most of the child classes will only alter a handful of them (but still need all the others present).  For instance, F could alter Features["1"], while the next class would leave ["1"] alone, but alter ["2"] and ["4"].